# Google Spanner - Get total COUNT then LIMIT OFFSET

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-spanner

New to Spanner, but not to SQL. Just wondering if there is a slick (read optimized) way to get the total records for a select query and then execute the same query with a LIMIT and OFFSET. Similar to this:

```
SELECT COUNT(1) FROM table WHERE Yada Yada
```

and record the total, then

```
SELECT columns FROM table WHERE Yada Yada LIMIT number OFFSET number
```

or this

```
SELECT (SELECT COUNT(1) FROM table WHERE Yada Yada) AS Total, columns FROM table 
WHERE Yada Yada LIMIT number OFFSET number
```

I can honestly say this is how I would also do it in SQL Server, perhaps naively, but just wondering if this the only way?

Answer (score 0):

Both approaches described above works, however both approaches would result in two scans. With the later approach, where one request is sent, there are fewer round trips between the client and Spanner.